# $(selector).flexslider ({ before: function() }) issue - skips first slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

Trying to relocate captions on flexslider,thought I could do:
`var myP = $('p.flex-caption').detach().appendTo(x);`
where x would be whatever element I wanted the captions to appear after.
In practice it works *ok* - I get a dump of all of the captions instead of just the one associated with the active slide but that may be just a css thing -the bigger problem is this doesn't happen until the second slide. I am calling this inside of flexslider.js, (pasted below) inside of $(selector).flexslider and inside of 'before' - I'm guessing the problem has something to do with how things are loaded. In an alternate approach, instead of using detach() to just pluck the p off and re-locate it, I tried creating an element - captionDiv - inside of which another created element - caption  - would get filled with the html returned from querying slider.slides[slider.animatingTo] but, again, the first caption wouldn't appear.

```
$(selector).flexslider( {
        smoothHeight: options.h_responsive,
             animation: options.animation,
             direction: options.direction,
             slideshow: options.slideshow,
             slideshowSpeed: Number( options.cycle_speed ) * 1000,
             animationSpeed: Number( options.animation_speed ) * 1000,
             pauseOnHover: options.pause_on_hover,
             controlNav: options.control_nav,
             directionNav: options.direction_nav,
             keyboard: options.keyboard_nav,
             touch: options.touch_nav,
             before: function( slider ) {
               slider.removeClass('loading');
               //added for outside caption
               //var sgmCaption = $('p.flex-caption');
               var tnh = $('div.flex-thumbnail-holder');
               //sgmCaption.detach().appendTo(tnh);
               if (!slider.captionDiv) {
                   slider.captionDiv = document.createElement("div");
                   slider.captionDiv.setAttribute("class", $(slider)[0].getAttribute("id") + "-caption flex-outside-caption");
                   //$(slider.captionDiv).insertAfter($(slider));
                   $(slider.captionDiv).insertAfter($(tnh));
               }

               var caption = slider.slides[slider.animatingTo].querySelector('.flex-caption');
               slider.captionDiv.innerHTML = caption ? caption.innerHTML : "";

             }

           });
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per documentation:

```
$(selector).flexslider({
    // Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider loads the first slide
    start: function(){},
    // Callback: function(slider) - Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
    before: function(){}
});
```

`before` callback is fired only when animation between slides starts. You need to prepare the caption of the first slide yourself - after hooking up or in the `start` callback.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! I duplicated the code and placed it in start() as well as as before(); I'm not sure which gets called first - start or before and which I should initialize vars in?

Comment: `start` is definitely called first, because it gets called during setup (page load?) and `before` gets called after user slides.